# Just one Question?

Tags: bug

When I click the questions link, only one question shows on the list. The rest are still there if you navigate to them through other means. Is anyone else observing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

And like that it's fixed. Does anyone know what caused this?

Comment: No idea. Do you have any ignored tags set up?

Comment: Looks like I was filtered to questions with a bounty on them...there was nothing denoting that but I was.

Comment: The "featured" tab should be bolded when you're on it. I agree that it's not very easy to notice that though.